# regex to migrate kotlin syntetic to viewBinding

Tags: android, regex, android-studio, kotlin

calling layout id from xml to activity using kotlin-syntetic could be the same as the id from xml

but when migrating from kotlin-syntetic to viewBinding, i need to change every layout id usage in activity.kt file from `tv_someword_middle_last` to `tvSomewordMiddleLast`

i wonder how to do "replace All" in android studio using regex against this pattern?

this should be like

```
find: (_)(a-z)
```

```
replace: (A-Z)
```

but i still dont know how to do so

thank you..

Comment: Try `_([a-z])` and replace with `\U$1`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks. i check the `(_)([a-z])` match when finding, but when replace using `\U$1` makes the character disappear, but the underscore still visible. it's one step closer..

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i tried in java, `myString.replaceAll("_([a-z])","\\U$1");` doesn't works too

Comment: No, in Java, you need `Pattern.compile("_([a-z])").matcher(example).replaceAll(r -> m.group(1).toUpperCase() )`, see https://ideone.com/o6snKC. And I told to replace **`_([a-z])`** with **`\U$1`**, NOT `(_)([a-z])` (where the Group 1 value is `_`, of course it will stay and the letter will disappear).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, it works using Pattern.compile(..) using your code. maybe to do this replace-all operation i should create script instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Android Studio search and replace feature supports case changing operators in the replacement patterns, you can use

```
_([a-z])
```

and replace with `\U$1`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4VloBg/1). The `_` is not captured, it is just matched. `([a-z])` creates a capturing group with ID 1 (it can be referred to with `$1` from the replacement pattern), and matches a lowercase ASCII letter. The `\U` in the replacement - if supported - makes the part of the replacement to the right of it uppercase.

Else, you can use the following [Java code](https://ideone.com/o6snKC):

```java
String example = "tv_someword_middle_last";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("_([a-z])").matcher(example);
example = m.replaceAll(r -> m.group(1).toUpperCase() );
System.out.println( example );
// => tvSomewordMiddleLast
```

Comment: thanks sir. for anyone who wants to do this find-and-replace-all operation could copy the code and paste to the given regex demo link. the result will be available